# Delete data before INSERT

Tags: mysql, mariadb, insert, mariadb-10.3

I have this table which is used to generate second table with the result:

```
INSERT INTO payment_transactions_daily_facts (count, volume, date, year, month, week, day, transaction_type, contract_id, merchant_id, terminal_id, status, card_brand, currency)
SELECT
        COUNT(*) count,
        SUM(amount) volume,
        DATE(created_at) date,
        YEAR(created_at) year,
        MONTH(created_at) month,
        WEEK(created_at) week,
        DAY(created_at) day,
        type transaction_type,
        contract_id, merchant_id, terminal_id,
        status, card_brand, currency
        FROM payment_transactions
        WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2018-11-11' AND '2018-11-14'
        GROUP by date, contract_id, merchant_id, terminal_id, transaction_type, status, card_brand, currency
```

But I need to delete the old data before I make insert. Is there a way with one SQL to delete first the table data starting from some date and them to insert a new one?

Comment: No. Two separate queries only.

Comment: If each `INSERT` only had to replace one single row, you could use [`REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replace/).

Comment: Can you show me working example from my code please?

Comment: Search for IODKU.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can issue a `DELETE` statement before your `INSERT`. If you do it inside a transaction, they will be essentially one operation, they will either fail or succeed together (assuming that the table uses a transactional engine, like InnoDB):

```
START TRANSACTION ;

    DELETE FROM
        payment_transactions_daily_facts
    WHERE
        date BETWEEN '2018-11-11' AND '2018-11-14' ;

    INSERT INTO
        payment_transactions_daily_facts
        (count, volume, date, ...)
    SELECT
         ...  ;

COMMIT ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use stored procedure. Here is a tutorial for MySQL stored procedures http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Alternatively google "MySQL stored procedures" for plenty of other readings.

Comment: Is there a solution without stored procedure?

Comment: as far as I know the answer is no. but you can execute multiple sql statements (without stored procedures) by seperating the statements with semi-colon ; (thats what i do in SQL Server, guess its the same in mysql). PL SQL (oracle) uses forward slash (/). For example: "delete from products where id=1; insert into select * from inventory;" would execute the delete first then select

Comment: You still need use a transaction, even if you write a stored procedure to do this.